# Android GPS takes too much time to get the location

Tags: android, gps

In my app the GPS takes too much time to get the location.

How can I use GPS from GPS_SATELLITES and GPS _NETWORK_PROVIDERS simultaneously in the same context and get the value of the recent GPS?

Answer (score 5):

Keep track of a `Location` object that is your current location. Request location updates from both

```
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            LOCATION_UPDATE_FREQUENCY, LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_DISTANCE,
            gpsListener);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_UPDATE_FREQUENCY,
            LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_DISTANCE, networkListener);
```

then when you get a response in `onLocationChanged` of either listener, either simply replace the Location variable you stored or replace it only if it is `X` seconds more recent, `X%` more accurate, `X` meters distant from your last reading, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `LocationManager.getAllProviders()`, then call `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)` to retrieve the last location each available provider found the last time it was called. This way, if another app used the GPS a minute ago, you can just go ahead and trust that they user hasn't made it that far away without hunting for satellites all over again.